# Clickable Dynamic Output Text react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Goal:**

1. Input text into two *textInput* fields (title text + body text)
2. Click submit *TouchableHighlight* button
3. The title only, gets rendered into the view
4. Click the title to advance to 'message view', where title **and** body text are displayed

Right now, I have the title displayed to the view as intended, on submit.
*(This current code sample only shows my title, I've exempted the body textInput for simplicity)*

```
Class Postings extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            inputText: '',
            textBucket: [] // all inputText will be added to array
        }
    }

        render() {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>Enter text below</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        onChange{(event) => this.setState({inputText: event.nativeEvent.text})}
                        value={this.state.textInput} />
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={(this.submitHandler.bind(this))}>
                        <Text>Submit</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>


                    // Below is the rendered output from inputText

                    {this.state.textBucket.map((inputvalue, i) => <Text key={i}>{inputvalue}</Text>)}
                </View>
            );
        }


        // Add each input item into the text bucket array

        submitHandler() {
            var inputText = this.state.inputText;
            var textBucket = this.state.inputText;
            this.setState({textBucket: textBucket.concat(inputText)})
        }

    }
```

How do I keep track of the posted message, so it can be clicked, and navigated to a new view, passing the title and body text with it?

My thought was to create a new function called `nextViewHandler()` that possibly takes in the current index from the `map()` function, controlling the outputted text... and then use something like:

```
nextViewHandler(index) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        component: NextView,
        passProps: { textBucket: this.state.items[index] },
    });
}
```

However I'm not sure if that would work.